# ReactJS <p/> or <br/> not working in render()

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, reactjs

I can't get `<p/>` or `<br/>` to create new lines when used after a custom ReactJS component that uses this Bootstrap CSS in the form `<div className="col-sm-10">` i.e.

```
var MyChatClientView = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Chat</h2>
        <span>Type something</span>

        <MyChatForm />

        <p/>
        <br/>

        <div>
           This text is on the same line as MyChatForm, I want it on a new line!
        </div>  
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var MyChatForm = React.createClass({

handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var myChatTxt = this.refs.myChatTxt.getDOMNode().value.trim();
 },

 render: function() {
    return (
    <div>
      <form role="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

        <div className="form-group">
           <input type="textarea" className="form-control" id="post-chat" ref="myChatTxt" />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <div className="col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Send</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To size form controls using Bootstrap, either (1) your form needs the `form-horizontal` class or (2) your columns need to be wrapped in an element with the `row` class.

This is covered in the [control sizing](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes) section of the Bootstrap docs.

In your case it seems to make sense to replace the `form-group` with the needed `row`:

```
var MyChatForm = React.createClass({

  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var myChatTxt = this.refs.myChatTxt.getDOMNode().value.trim();
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form role="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

          <div className="form-group">
             <input type="textarea" className="form-control" id="post-chat" ref="myChatTxt" />
          </div>

          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-10">
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Send</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```